# MySQL query data based on time

Tags: mysql, database

I have tables as follow:

```
create table company
(
    id int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
    name varchar(50) not null,
    primary key (id)
);

create table invoice
(
    id int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
    company_id int(10) unsigned not null,        
    invoice_number varchar(50) not null,
    paid_date datetime not null,
    paid_amount decimal(10, 2) not null,
    primary key (id),
    foreign key (company_id) references company(id)
);

create table company_rate
(
    id int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
    company_id int(10) unsigned not null,
    rate decimal(10, 2) not null,
    effective_date datetime not null,
    primary key (id),
    foreign key (company_id) references company(id)
);
```

Company table holds the name of companies.
Invoice table holds the invoice number, the date that the company get paid and the amount.
Company rate table holds the rate and the starting date when the rate is effective.
For example,

```
company_id    rate    effective_date
-------------------------------------
1              100        0000-00-00
1              350        2013-07-01
1              450        2013-07-20
1              500        2014-01-01
```

if current date is 07-03, then the rate is 350 and if date is 09-21, rate is 450 and so forth.

I'm trying to make a two functions based on those tables.

One is to create an invoice by selecting company and display current rate based on the effective date using html form or whatever.

The other one is to create a list like this:

```
company_name    invoice_number    rate    paid_amount    paid_date
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Apple           12345             300      300           2013-01-14
Apple           12346             500      400           2013-05-12
Intel           44441             1200     1350          2013-06-01
```

It prints invoice information and rate is determined by paid_date.

This was tried:

```
SELECT c.name as company_name, i.invoice_number, r.rate, i.paid_amount, i.paid_date 
FROM invoice as i 
    LEFT JOIN company as c on c.id = i.company_id 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT company_id, rate, effective_date 
            FROM  company_rate 
            WHERE effective_date IN (
                SELECT MAX(effective_date) 
                    FROM company_rate 
                        GROUP BY company_id
     )) AS r ON r.company_id = c.id 
         AND r.effective_date <= i.paid_date
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: And what do you mean by 'functions' - do you mean queries directly on there database or as part of an application built on top of the database?

Comment: At the very beginning I used 'select c.name as company_name, i.invoice_number, r.rate, i.paid_amount, i.paid_date from invoice as i left join company as c on c.id = i.company_id left join (select company_id, rate, effective_date from company_rate where effective_date in (select max(effective_date) from company_rate group by company_id) as r on r.company_id = c.id and r.effective_date <= i.paid_date' and I realized that it only gets the latest effective date. Then I was not sure how to approach this so I posted the question.

Comment: I meant 'functions' as part of an application but what I need is how to get the correct rate with corresponding date to make the 'functions' working correctly. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Your SQL does not seem to work at all: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1cf2d5/2

Comment: missing ')' right after 'by company_id)'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to use a correlated subquery

```
SELECT c.name, invoice_number, 
       (SELECT rate
          FROM company_rate 
         WHERE company_id = i.company_id
           AND effective_date <= i.paid_date
         ORDER BY effective_date DESC
         LIMIT 1) rate,
       paid_amount,
       paid_date
  FROM invoice i JOIN company c
    ON i.company_id = c.id
```

Sample output:

```
|     NAME | INVOICE_NUMBER | RATE | PAID_AMOUNT |                      PAID_DATE |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Company1 |          12345 |  100 |         300 | January, 14 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
| Company1 |          12346 |  350 |         400 |     May, 12 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
| Company2 |          44441 | 1200 |        1350 |    June, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30530/1)** demo

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I figured out how to find the correct rate but didn't know how merge it to the list because join cannot use outside variable. Learned something new. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are posting this under the MySQL tag, I think you are looking for "pure sql" solutions, so here are my suggestions. I'll help you with the first situation, and let you work out the second one (should be easy once you understand how to work out the first).

**Get the latest rate.**

So you want to get the latest rate based on a "current" date. You could achieve this with a subquery:

```
select 
    cr.*
from 
    company_rate as cr
    inner join (
        select company_id, max(date) as maxDate
        from company_rate
        where company_id = @yourCompanyId  -- Set (or replace) the variable with the desired value
          and date <= @yourDate  -- Set (or replace) the variable with the desired value
        group by company_id
    )
```